# Two tables share input

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, html-table

I have two tables, the top needs to share input to the bottom after the field has been filled out. The input needs to match row by row (not everything added or all in one field). I believe I am very close I am just having an issue getting it to work.

These are my tables:

```
<script id="line-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <tr>
  <td class="td-sm text-left number"><span data-name="print_number"></span></td>
  <td class="td-sm">
      <input name="purchase_order[items][][code]" placeholder="Code" class="form-control purchase_order_line_code" value="{{ item.code }}" autocomplete="off">
      <input type="hidden" name="purchase_order[items][][id]" value="{{ item.id }}">
    </td>
    <td class="td-sm"><input name="purchase_order[items][][quantity]" data-name="quantity" placeholder="0" class="form-control" value="{{ item.quantity }}"></td>
    <td class="td-sm"><input name="purchase_order[items][][unit_of_measure]" placeholder="Units" class="form-control" value="{{ item.unit_of_measure }}"></td>
    <td class="td-md"><input name="purchase_order[items][][lf_sf_each]" data-name="lf_sf_each" placeholder="0" class="form-control" value="{{ item.unit_each }}"></td>
    <td><input name="purchase_order[items][][description]" data-name="description" placeholder="Description" class="form-control purchase_order_line_description" value="{{ item.description }}"></td>

    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="unit_breakdown">0</span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right first"><input name="purchase_order[items][][unit_price]" data-name="unit_price" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control unit_price" value="{{ item.unit_price }}"></td>

    <td class="td-sm text-right"><input name="purchase_order[items][][unit_amount]" data-name="unit_amount" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control" value="{{ item.unit_price }}"></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="extend_price"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="price_per_pc">0</span></td>

    <td class="td-sm text-right"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parents('tr').remove(); return false" class="text-danger"><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg></span></a></td>
  </tr>
</script>

<script id="second-line-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <tr>
    <td class="td-sm text-left"><span data-name="second_print_number"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-left"><span data-name="second_description"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-left"><span data-name="quantity_ordered_extended"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="total_needed"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="above_price"></span></td>

    <td class="td-sm text-right"><input name="purchase_order[items][][invoice_one]" data-name="invoice_one" placeholder="0" class="form-control" value="{{ item.invoice_one }}"></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="invoice_dollar_one"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><input name="purchase_order[items][][invoice_two]" data-name="invoice_two" placeholder="0" class="form-control" value="{{ item.invoice_two }}"></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="invoice_dollar_two"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><input name="purchase_order[items][][invoice_three]" data-name="invoice_three" placeholder="0" class="form-control" value="{{ item.invoice_three }}"></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="invoice_dollar_three"></span></td>
    <td class="td-sm text-right"><span data-name="total_recieved"></span></td>


    <td class="td-sm text-right"><a href="#" onclick="$(this).parents('tr').remove(); return false" class="text-danger"><span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-x-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line><line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line></svg></span></a></td>
  </tr>
</script>
```

This is the Javascript I have so far:

```
// PO lines
  $('#purchase-order-form-lines tbody tr').each(function(k, v) {
    var line = {};
    $('input[data-name]', v).each(function(i, c) {
      line[$(c).data('name')] = parseFloat($(c).val()) || 0;
    });

    price_from_above = line.unit_price; 
    quantity_from_above = line.quantity;
    description_from_above = line.description;

    line.print_number = 1;

    line.unit_breakdown = line.quantity * line.lf_sf_each;
    line.extend_price = line.unit_breakdown * line.unit_price;
    line.price_per_pc = Math.round(line.extend_price * 100) / (line.quantity * 100);
    subtotal += line.extend_price;
    taxtotal = (taxPercent * subtotal) / 100;
    discounttotal = (discountPercent * subtotal) / 100;

    line.breakdown = line.quantity * line.each;
    line.total = line.breakdown * line.unit_price;
    line.received_total = ((line.received || 0) + (line.received_2 || 0) + (line.received_3 || 0) + (line.received_4 || 0) + (line.received_5 || 0)) * line.each * line.unit_price;
    receivedSubtotal += line.received_total;

    $('[data-name="print_number"]', v).html(line.print_number);
    $('[data-name="unit_breakdown"]', v).html(line.unit_breakdown);
    $('[data-name="extend_price"]', v).html(line.extend_price.formatMoney(2));
    $('[data-name="price_per_pc"]', v).html(line.price_per_pc.formatMoney(2));

    $('[data-name="breakdown"]', v).html(line.breakdown);
    $('[data-name="total"]', v).html(line.total.formatMoney(2));
    $('[data-name="received_total"]', v).html(line.received_total.formatMoney(2));
  });

    // PO second lines
    $('#purchase-order-form-second-lines tbody tr').each(function(k, v) {
      var secondline = {};
      $('input[data-name]', v).each(function(i, c) {
        secondline[$(c).data('name')] = parseFloat($(c).val()) || 0;
      });

      secondline.second_print_number = 2;
      secondline.second_description = description_from_above;
      secondline.quantity_ordered_extended = quantity_from_above;
      secondline.total_needed = quantity_from_above - secondline.invoice_one - secondline.invoice_two - secondline.invoice_three;
      secondline.above_price = data;

      secondline.invoice_dollar_one = secondline.above_price * secondline.invoice_one;
      secondline.invoice_dollar_two = secondline.above_price * secondline.invoice_two;
      secondline.invoice_dollar_three = secondline.above_price * secondline.invoice_three;

      secondline.total_recieved = secondline.invoice_dollar_one + secondline.invoice_dollar_two + secondline.invoice_dollar_three;

      viewFirstSubtotal = secondline.invoice_dollar_one;
      viewSecondSubtotal = secondline.invoice_dollar_two;
      viewThirdSubtotal = secondline.invoice_dollar_three;

      second_discount = discountPercent;
      viewFirstDiscount = (discountPercent * secondline.invoice_dollar_one) / 100;
      viewSecondDiscount = (discountPercent * secondline.invoice_dollar_two) / 100;
      viewThirdDiscount = (discountPercent * secondline.invoice_dollar_three) / 100;

      second_tax = taxPercent;
      viewFirstTax = (taxPercent * secondline.invoice_dollar_one) / 100;
      viewSecondTax = (taxPercent * secondline.invoice_dollar_two) / 100;
      viewThirdTax = (taxPercent * secondline.invoice_dollar_three) / 100;

      viewFirstTotalInvoice = viewFirstSubtotal - viewFirstDiscount + viewFirstTax;
      viewSecondTotalInvoice = viewSecondSubtotal - viewSecondDiscount + viewSecondTax;
      viewThirdTotalInvoice = viewThirdSubtotal - viewThirdDiscount + viewThirdTax;

      $('[data-name="second_print_number"]', v).html(secondline.second_print_number);
      $('[data-name="second_description"]', v).html(secondline.second_description);
      $('[data-name="quantity_ordered_extended"]', v).html(secondline.quantity_ordered_extended);
      $('[data-name="total_needed"]', v).html(secondline.total_needed);
      $('[data-name="above_price"]', v).html(secondline.above_price);

      $('[data-name="invoice_dollar_one"]', v).html(secondline.invoice_dollar_one.formatMoney(2));
      $('[data-name="invoice_dollar_two"]', v).html(secondline.invoice_dollar_two.formatMoney(2));
      $('[data-name="invoice_dollar_three"]', v).html(secondline.invoice_dollar_three.formatMoney(2));
      $('[data-name="total_recieved"]', v).html(secondline.total_recieved.formatMoney(2));
    });
```

I am trying to get the column for the unit price to go from the top table to the bottom row by row. I realize this is a lot of code I just wanted to make sure that it is all there for reference.

I have found this code online and have been trying to manipulate it so that I can achieve my goal but so far I have not been able to get it to do exactly what I want:

```
 $("#purchase-order-form-lines, #purchase-order-form-second-lines").on('click', '.btnSelection', function() {
    // get the current row
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");

    var col1 = currentRow.find(".first").html(); // get current row 1st table cell TD value

    var data = col1;
  });
```

Any thoughts or input would be greatly appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful if you put your working code on something like codepen.io so we can help you better.

Comment: This code is very complex for what you're trying to do. *write less, do more* - jQuery

Comment: several of your variables (e.g. `viewFirstSubtotal`) appear to be created as implicit globals. This can cause very strange problems...recommend adding `'use strict';` at the top of your script tag. It will error if you have undeclared variables instead of making them implicit globals.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is part of a ruby on rails project but I can try to make a codepen however I'm not sure how good it will look compared to my full ruby project. I know @kemicofa I actually inherited the project from a previous coworker so I am trying to do the best I can especially being new to code and ruby, but do you have any helpful ideas or input to achieve my goal?

Comment: @ProfessionallyInept I possibly could if I knew what the end goal was in a clear way. I admit that the effort of understanding all that code would seem tiring. If you could provide me with a clear understanding of what you're trying to do, I could provide a script that may point you in the right direction.

Comment: @kemicofa sorry if I came off as rude I just reread my comment and could feel my frustration from this issue oozing out of the text. I have two tables with input fields and I am trying to get the input from the unit price column to go from the top table to the bottom table. I am able to achieve this however I need it to go row from row (as in unit price from row 1 on the top table to go to unit price in row 1 on the bottom table) and that is my main issue. I hope that's more clear my brain is kind of burnt out from trying to figure this out.

Comment: @ProfessionallyInept do you have enough rep to join this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187344/geekdpt ?

Comment: @kemicofa I don't unfortunately my rep is 16 and I need 20 to talk in that chat.